# Unable to install openJDK 8 in Red Hat

Tags: linux, yum, redhat-openjdk

I am trying to install openJDK 8 in my machine using yum, as per this https://openjdk.java.net/install/ .

But I can't see open openJDK 8 in yum repository.

```
[root@test ~]# yum search jdk
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, product-id, refresh-packagekit, security,
              : subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
=============================== N/S Matched: jdk ===============================
java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
java-1.6.0-openjdk-javadoc.x86_64 : OpenJDK API Documentation
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 : OpenJDK Development Environment
java-1.7.0-openjdk-javadoc.noarch : OpenJDK API Documentation
icedtea-web.x86_64 : Additional Java components for OpenJDK - Java browser
                   : plug-in and Web Start implementation
ldapjdk.x86_64 : The Mozilla LDAP Java SDK
```

yum.conf file:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=3
exclude=mongodb-org,mongodb-org-server,mongodb-org-shell,mongodb-org-mongos,mongodb-org-tools
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your version is too old you don't have the packages included or you have to enable some more repositories first to get the packages.

To list enabled repos:

```
subscription-manager repos --list-enabled
```

To enable third party repo:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

When your version isn't to old you can make an `yum update` and fetch all new packages. Then you should be able to install JDK 8. Here is another good tutorial how to install JDK-8 on Red-Hat.

https://developers.redhat.com/articles/using-java-rhel-7-openjdk-8/

If you use an older Red-Hat version you have to install it on your own.

https://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/

Comment: I'm using Red-Hat 6.5. I'm getting below message while enabling, any help would be appreciated. `[root@test ~]# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
Repositories disabled by configuration.`

Comment: Then try the following link in my post. There is an example how to install it from source.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.