# AWS - Can't Install Java 1.8 on RHEL

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

So i have an aws (amazon) instance running **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)**.  I'm attempting to install java 1.8

Question:

What am I doing wrong and how do I install java?

Command:

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Error

```
Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
           Requires: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Full Terminal Output

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras                                                                                         | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases                                                                                       | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common                                                                                      | 3.8 kB  00:00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjava.so()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjvm.so()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: fontconfig(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: gtk2(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXcomposite(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9.0rc4)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXext.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXi.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXrender.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXtst.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libasound.so.2()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgif.so.4()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: copy-jdk-configs >= 3.3 for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: tzdata-java >= 2015d for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: cups-libs(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: jpackage-utils for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lksctp-tools(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package libX11.x86_64 0:1.6.5-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libX11-common >= 1.6.5-2.el7 for package: libX11-1.6.5-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1()(64bit) for package: libX11-1.6.5-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package alsa-lib.x86_64 0:1.1.6-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package copy-jdk-configs.noarch 0:3.3-10.el7_5 will be installed
---> Package cups-libs.x86_64 1:1.6.3-35.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libavahi-client.so.3()(64bit) for package: 1:cups-libs-1.6.3-35.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libavahi-common.so.3()(64bit) for package: 1:cups-libs-1.6.3-35.el7.x86_64
---> Package fontconfig.x86_64 0:2.13.0-4.3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: dejavu-sans-fonts for package: fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: fontpackages-filesystem for package: fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.el7.x86_64
---> Package giflib.x86_64 0:4.1.6-9.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libICE.so.6()(64bit) for package: giflib-4.1.6-9.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libSM.so.6()(64bit) for package: giflib-4.1.6-9.el7.x86_64
---> Package gtk2.x86_64 0:2.24.31-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: atk >= 1.29.4-2 for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXrandr >= 1.2.99.4-2 for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libtiff >= 3.6.1 for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pango >= 1.20.0-1 for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: gtk-update-icon-cache for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: hicolor-icon-theme for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXcursor.so.1()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXdamage.so.1()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXfixes.so.3()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXinerama.so.1()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXrandr.so.2()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcairo.so.2()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpango-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpangocairo-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpangoft2-1.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: gtk2-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package javapackages-tools.noarch 0:3.4.1-11.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-javapackages = 3.4.1-11.el7 for package: javapackages-tools-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch
---> Package libX11-common.noarch 0:1.6.5-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXcomposite.x86_64 0:0.4.4-4.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXext.x86_64 0:1.3.3-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXi.x86_64 0:1.7.9-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXrender.x86_64 0:0.9.10-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXtst.x86_64 0:1.2.3-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libjpeg-turbo.x86_64 0:1.2.90-6.el7 will be installed
---> Package libxcb.x86_64 0:1.13-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6()(64bit) for package: libxcb-1.13-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package lksctp-tools.x86_64 0:1.0.17-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package tzdata-java.noarch 0:2018i-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch 0:7.5-9.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mkfontdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mkfontdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ttmkfdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ttmkfdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package atk.x86_64 0:2.28.1-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package avahi-libs.x86_64 0:0.6.31-19.el7 will be installed
---> Package cairo.x86_64 0:1.15.12-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libEGL.so.1()(64bit) for package: cairo-1.15.12-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libGL.so.1()(64bit) for package: cairo-1.15.12-3.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpixman-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: cairo-1.15.12-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: dejavu-fonts-common = 2.33-6.el7 for package: dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-6.el7.noarch
---> Package fontpackages-filesystem.noarch 0:1.44-8.el7 will be installed
---> Package gdk-pixbuf2.x86_64 0:2.36.12-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libjasper.so.1()(64bit) for package: gdk-pixbuf2-2.36.12-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package gtk-update-icon-cache.x86_64 0:3.22.30-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package hicolor-icon-theme.noarch 0:0.12-7.el7 will be installed
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package libICE.x86_64 0:1.0.9-9.el7 will be installed
---> Package libSM.x86_64 0:1.2.2-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.8-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXcursor.x86_64 0:1.1.15-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXdamage.x86_64 0:1.1.4-4.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXfixes.x86_64 0:5.0.3-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXinerama.x86_64 0:1.1.3-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXrandr.x86_64 0:1.5.1-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libtiff.x86_64 0:4.0.3-27.el7_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libjbig.so.2.0()(64bit) for package: libtiff-4.0.3-27.el7_3.x86_64
---> Package pango.x86_64 0:1.42.4-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: fribidi(x86-64) >= 1.0 for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: harfbuzz(x86-64) >= 1.4.2 for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXft(x86-64) >= 2.0.0 for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libthai(x86-64) >= 0.1.9 for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libthai.so.0(LIBTHAI_0.1)(64bit) for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXft.so.2()(64bit) for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfribidi.so.0()(64bit) for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libharfbuzz.so.0()(64bit) for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libthai.so.0()(64bit) for package: pango-1.42.4-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package python-javapackages.noarch 0:3.4.1-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package ttmkfdir.x86_64 0:3.0.9-42.el7 will be installed
---> Package xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64 1:7.5-21.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfontenc.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-21.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dejavu-fonts-common.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
---> Package fribidi.x86_64 0:1.0.2-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package harfbuzz.x86_64 0:1.7.5-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgraphite2.so.3()(64bit) for package: harfbuzz-1.7.5-2.el7.x86_64
---> Package jasper-libs.x86_64 0:1.900.1-33.el7 will be installed
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package jbigkit-libs.x86_64 0:2.0-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXft.x86_64 0:2.3.2-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libfontenc.x86_64 0:1.1.3-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libglvnd-egl.x86_64 1:1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libglvnd(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7 for package: 1:libglvnd-egl-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: mesa-libEGL(x86-64) >= 13.0.4-1 for package: 1:libglvnd-egl-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libGLdispatch.so.0()(64bit) for package: 1:libglvnd-egl-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
---> Package libglvnd-glx.x86_64 1:1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mesa-libGL(x86-64) >= 13.0.4-1 for package: 1:libglvnd-glx-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
---> Package libthai.x86_64 0:0.1.14-9.el7 will be installed
---> Package pixman.x86_64 0:0.34.0-1.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package graphite2.x86_64 0:1.3.10-1.el7_3 will be installed
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package libglvnd.x86_64 1:1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7 will be installed
---> Package mesa-libEGL.x86_64 0:18.0.5-4.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mesa-libgbm = 18.0.5-4.el7_6 for package: mesa-libEGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdrm.so.2()(64bit) for package: mesa-libEGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgbm.so.1()(64bit) for package: mesa-libEGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libglapi.so.0()(64bit) for package: mesa-libEGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwayland-client.so.0()(64bit) for package: mesa-libEGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwayland-server.so.0()(64bit) for package: mesa-libEGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxshmfence.so.1()(64bit) for package: mesa-libEGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package mesa-libGL.x86_64 0:18.0.5-4.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXxf86vm.so.1()(64bit) for package: mesa-libGL-18.0.5-4.el7_6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package libXxf86vm.x86_64 0:1.1.4-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libdrm.x86_64 0:2.4.91-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpciaccess.so.0()(64bit) for package: libdrm-2.4.91-3.el7.x86_64
---> Package libwayland-client.x86_64 0:1.15.0-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libwayland-server.x86_64 0:1.15.0-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libxshmfence.x86_64 0:1.2-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package mesa-libgbm.x86_64 0:18.0.5-4.el7_6 will be installed
---> Package mesa-libglapi.x86_64 0:18.0.5-4.el7_6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64
---> Package libpciaccess.x86_64 0:0.14-1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
           Requires: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Have you tried `yum install pcsc-lite-devel` to see if it will install on its own?

Comment: yum install pcsc-lite-devel
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, rhui-lb, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
No package pcsc-lite-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: The package appears to be missing from the repository the last few days, Red Hat seem to be aware

Comment: You can fix it with `yumdownloader --resolve java-1.8.0-openjdk`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67616102/658497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used the following command and it installed

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work on RHEL 7.5.  Same error message about pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64) dependency.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

```
$ su -
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
# yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Fuller explanation:
[Unable to install openJDK 8 in Red Hat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004627/unable-to-install-openjdk-8-in-red-hat/54005343#54005343)

Comment: i get this :
subscription-manager repos --list-enabled
This system has no repositories available through subscriptions.
[root@]# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
Error: 'rhel-7-server-optional-rpms' does not match a valid repository ID. Use "subscription-manager repos --list" to see valid repositories.

Comment: @Lacer  if the command errors out suggesting a second command to help you find the right repo, what does running the suggested command produce?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.

Surprisingly, on the 26/02/2019 I installed `java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64` in a RHEL 7.6 machine, (ami was ami-0e12cbde3e77cbb98).

Today I tried running a yum install of the same package and errors.

**EDIT**

Give this a try, I am currently testing it:

```
sudo yum -y install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/pcsc-lite-devel-1.8.8-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

This might not be the way RHEL supports it though, but is a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

It was a repository glitch. I had same issue last week but didn't have time to open case to RH. Today i checked again and pcsc-lite is available on rhel-7-server-rpms so all went well and dependencies were resolved.
Make sure you cleanup your repo data before running yum install and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional

yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

tested on redhat 7.4 only needed optional rpms

yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional

yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Comment: Please add more specific information about your answer. this is not good kind of answer.

Comment: I tried this answer and it doesn't work. The error message remains unchanged.   Is "REGION" something we need to substitute or are these commands to be typed as written?

Answer (score 0):

we have the same issue on AWS using an RHEL-7.4_HVM_GA-20170808-x86_64-2-Hourly2-GP2 (ami-bb9a6bc2) instance

suddenly we had

Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.201.b09-0.el7_6.x86_64 (rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases)
           Requires: pcsc-lite-devel(x86-64)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

As the release doesn't come with a support contract with Redhat we are somewhat stuck

Has anyone got any pointers to help us? for the moment we directing to an internal rpm using an s3 location ie

yum install -y https://s3-xxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the Redhat repositories. The required package was missing. It has been fixed. Run yum update and it will download all the requirements now.

Answer (score 0):

Most packages dependency problems in RHEL, like this:

> Error: Package:
> 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64
> (rhel-7-workstation-rpms)
> Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9
> Installed: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64
> (@rhel-7-workstation-rpms)

Can be resolved with ***yumdownloader***, which downloads all required packages:

```
$ sudo yum install yum-utils
$ yumdownloader java-1.8.0-openjdk --resolve --destdir pkgs

  ...
  --> Finished Dependency Resolution
  (1/6): giflib-4.1.6-9.el7.i686.rpm   |  40 kB  00:00:01     
  (2/6): java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64.rpm   | 307 kB  00:00:01     
  (3/6): java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282.b08-1.el7_9.i686.rpm   | 306 kB  00:00:02     
  (4/6): lksctp-tools-1.0.17-2.el7.i686.rpm   |  85 kB  00:00:00     
  (5/6): pcsc-lite-libs-1.8.8-8.el7.i686.rpm   |  35 kB  00:00:00     
  (6/6): java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.282.b08-1.el7_9.i686.rpm
```

Then you can install them all at once:

```
$ sudo yum install pkgs/*.rpm
```